# Install Sikuli on RHEL without subscription

Tags: selenium, rhel, sikuli

Is it possible to install Sikuli (and possibly Selenium) on a RHEL machine that does not have a subscription?

I was able to successfully download the Sikuli (and Selenium) packages however I can not run it due to a dependency error.

I know that this is tedious work, however I just want to know whether or not it is possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be possible. You can try to change the repository to another distro (like [How to enable EPEL](https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/236625)), and after that, you can follow this [link](https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/236625) to install sikuli :-]: